# Firebase Real Time Database , is it secure?

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Working with Firebase and Android Studio i have a big security question about it.

the current rules of Firebase Real Time Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
   }
}
```

so a User must login using Firebase authentication , the idea of my app is to read data and write data for all users.

My authentication allows even Anonymous users to login and my question is 
is it secure ?

What if one will reverse engineer my app and could possibly login into my database using java code he wrote and change stuff in my database ?

Am i (the developer) is the only one who gets the ability to access me database
or if someone hacks my app and rebuild it will have the same login ?

And how safe is Firebase anyways, is it really a good solution for now with no server side capabilities ? as it will take me some time to learn and the app could be released before ...

Should i pay for some expert Joe to build my Firebase defenses ?

How secure is it ?

thanks in advance.